# Comparing sqlite error message in C

Tags: mysql, c, database

I am facing one obstacle in my application . In the previous software we had a database without any version field . This time i am adding it into the database.

Basically we have 2 database files 1: read/write and 2: readonly . I am updating the read only db and updating the software . During run time program will check if there's a change in the readonly db then it will replace this db with read/write db file.

Problem is when sqlite detects a new column it will through an error "no such column "dbversion" " . I want to handle this message and call my db replacing function.

Code follows like this.

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_handle , query_getGlobalAudioPropVersion , -1, &stmt_getGlobalAudioPropVersion , NULL);
        if ( rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            ALOGE("Line : %d sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed with error : %s retval : %d\n",__LINE__, sqlite3_errmsg(db_handle),rc);
            //ret = AUDMGR_ERR_SQLITE_OPERATION_FAILED;

            strcpy(message , sqlite3_errmsg(db_handle));
            if(strncmp(message,"no such",8)==0)
            {
                resetToFactoryDefaults();
            }
        }
```

I am copying the error message into a char 'message' and comparing it for 'no such' . It doesn't work . Please suggest some help.

Comment: Why you're putting `8`? try with `7`, like `if(strncmp(message,"no such",7)==0)`

Comment: Correct it seems i counted 8 . But do you think it will work for what i am trying ?

Comment: Not very sure. But anyway, comparing the terminating null is not going to work for sure, as `message` contains a longer string  :-)

Comment: Yeah correct the string is longer. What do you suggest ?

Comment: I already suggested the fix in my first comment, did you try that?

Comment: My device is rebooting continously , so i need to rebuild the entire code with this change . It takes 2 hours of time . i will update. Thank you

Comment: Try using strstr instead of strncmp.  That will detect any occurrence of "no such" in message.